# Can i get URL content without submitting it?

Tags: php, ajax, url, get

i generate link with

```
<a onclick="window.history.pushState('', '', '?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>');"
```

and it generated URL like this

```
http://localhost/dpmerzon/order.php?id=MT01
```

"MT01" is example id for every link i pressed

So can i get "MT01" value with (PHP) `$_GET['id']` without submitting the URL ?

Comment: Rethink this. You want to submit data to PHP without submitting it? You may want to explore AJAX to submit it silently in the background.

Comment: what do you mean bu "Without Submitting URL"?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use AJAX if you want to submit somthing in background 
explaine more what you gona do may can i help you